# Quarantining process in JFK/NYC?

Tags: covid-19, new-york-city, quarantine

Assuming I tested negative today for covid and I arrive at JFK the day after tomorrow, how does the 3-day quarantine process work? I'll be in NYC for 5 days.

So I arrive at JFK airport: do I have to go to a specific hotel for the 3-day quarantine or can I go to a hotel of my choice at Manhattan? Can I take a taxi to the hotel? Will someone make sure I don't leave before the 3 days?

I've never had to go into quarantine, so I don't know what the process is.

Answer (score 2):

There are exemptions from some of the below requirements for "essential" workers; see the  **[New York State COVID-19 Travel Advisory page](https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/covid-19-travel-advisory)** for all current public information and guidelines.

After arriving at JFK, whether domestic or international, you will be directed to complete the mandatory online New York traveler health form (https://traveler.health.ny.gov/ ). Depending on your answers, you may be contacted by the health department regarding your quarantine plans, but in general, staying alone a standard hotel room and eating only delivered food meets the facility guidelines:

> - The individual must not be in public or otherwise leave the quarters that they have identified as suitable.
> - Separate quarters with separate bathroom facilities for each individual or family group. Access to a sink with soap and water, and paper towels is needed.
> - The contact must have a way to self-quarantine from household members as soon as fever or other symptoms develop, in a separate room. There must be a door that separates it from the rest of the living area and has its own bathroom. Given that an exposed individual might become ill while sleeping, the exposed individual must sleep in a separate bedroom from household members.
> - Cleaning supplies, e.g. household cleaning wipes, must be provided in any shared bathroom.
> - If an individual sharing a bathroom becomes symptomatic, all others sharing the bathroom will be considered exposed persons until the symptomatic individual is appropriately evaluated and cleared.
> - Food must be delivered to the individual’s quarters.
> - Quarters must have a supply of face masks for individuals to put on if they become symptomatic.
> - Garbage must be bagged and left outside by the door of each of the quarters for routine pick up. Special handling is not required.
> - Individuals should self-monitor for fever and other symptoms of COVID-19 daily throughout the duration of the quarantine period.

You can take a taxi or any other method of transportation to your hotel, such as Uber/Lyft, subway, etc., provided you wear a mask of course.

You can request a test for your fourth day of your stay, and can exit quarantine if both this test and the one you took prior to departure are negative. Note that it commonly takes two to three days to obtain test results.

You won't be required to install a tracking app, and you won't have guards posted outside your door, but if someone does report you to the health department as not being in compliance, then the health department can take legal action such as a direct quarantine order or [fines up to $10,000](https://www.governor.ny.gov/news/no-2052-quarantine-restrictions-travelers-arriving-new-york).

---

The big picture view is that unless you are an "essential" worker, you will hardly leave your hotel room, if at all, before it is time to turn around and return home again. I have a hard time envisioning how a five-day trip would be worth the expense, given the present circumstances.